# CREATE VIEW in SQL Server using UNION ALL

Tags: sql-server

Please consider the below example:

```
CREATE VIEW VW_YearlySales
AS

SELECT 2011 AS YearNo, ProductID, SUM(Amount) FROM InvoiceTable2011
UNION ALL
SELECT 2012 AS YearNo, ProductID, SUM(Amount) FROM InvoiceTable2012
UNION ALL
SELECT 2013 AS YearNo, ProductID, SUM(Amount) FROM InvoiceTable2013

GO
```

The `InvoiceTable2013` doesn't exist actually and I don't want to create it right now, it will be created automatically when recording the first invoice for year 2013.

Can anyone help me on how to specify a condition that will verify the existence of the table before doing the `UNION ALL`?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you clarify: "The table does exist and I don't want to create it" => you meant _doesn't_ exist, right?

Comment: I realise you probably can't change it but it would be more efficient to have a single table. You probably have an invoice date in there which you can query.

Comment: Perhaps the process that automatically creates the new table should be responsible for updating the view definition as well. I think something like that is implemented in one of the project I've worked with, although I couldn't provide details at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

As others have correctly said, you can't achieve this with a view, because the select statement has to reference a concrete set of tables - and if any of them don't exist, the query will fail to execute.

It seems to me like your problem is more fundamental.  Clearly there should conceptually be exactly one `InvoiceTable`, with rows for different dates.  Separating this out into different logical tables by year is presumably something that's been done for optimisation (unless the columns are different, which I very much doubt).

In this case, [partitioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) seems like the way to remedy this problem (partitioning large tables by year/quarter/month is the canonical example).  This would let you have a single `InvoiceTable` logically, yet specify that SQL Server should store the data behind the scenes as if it were different tables split out by year.  You get the best of both worlds - an accurate model, and fast performance - and this makes your view definition simple.

Answer (score 1):

No, according to my knowledge its not possible in view, you have to use Stored Procedure. In Stored Procedure you can validate table existance & based on the existance of that table you can change your SQL.

**EDIT:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetYearlySales
AS

IF (EXISTS (SELECT *  
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  
                 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'InvoiceTable2013')) 
BEGIN 

   SELECT 2011 AS YearNo, ProductID, SUM(Amount) FROM InvoiceTable2011 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 2012 AS YearNo, ProductID, SUM(Amount) FROM InvoiceTable2012 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 2013 AS YearNo, ProductID, SUM(Amount) FROM InvoiceTable2013

END
ELSE
BEGIN
   SELECT 2011 AS YearNo, ProductID, SUM(Amount) FROM InvoiceTable2011 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 2012 AS YearNo, ProductID, SUM(Amount) FROM InvoiceTable2012
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to have a table for every year and you want to ensure that you have the query for SP without modifying the SP. This is slightly risky , you will have to maintain the naming conventions all the time. In this case what you will have to do is query the informationschema tables for table_name like 'InvoiceTable%'. Get the records in a table and then loop through the records attaching the fixed SQL. And then execute the dynamic sql like its done here http://www.vishalseth.com/post/2008/07/10/Dynamic-SQL-sp_executesql.aspx